# What is the use of FieldStorage in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know whats the difference between FieldStorage in Python and wsgi_input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FieldStorage` is useful in `CGI` contexts and can help in some other cases in which you want to do your own parsing and handling of (e.g.) a form posted (or also sent by a GET;-) to your server, without necessarily involving `WSGI` in any way.  It provided a nicely accessible, somewhat dict-like object for accessing the form data (whether in a POST or GET context).

I'm not sure what `wsgi_input` (with an underscore) *is*; if you mean `wsgi.input` (with a dot, and, normally, quotes around it;-), it's a key in a WSGI environment whose value must be, quoting from [PEP 333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#input-and-error-streams):

> An input stream (file-like object)
>   from which the HTTP request body can
>   be read.

So it only exists in a WSGI context and does not imply that any parsing of that request body has been done -- parsing of the request body (to receive POSTs, specifically), if any, must happen "using" that stream.